# How to convert from Uint to Int

Tags: chisel

I would like to use `Log2()` for bit width extraction in IO. Which `Log2()` is Uint, but bit-width declaration probably needs Int type. So, I want to convert (cast) from Uint to Int.

I tried to do as follow in IO;

```
val hoge = Output(Uint(Log2(BitWidth).W))
```

Then this produces an error of type-mismatch. I could not find UInt to Int conversion. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
val hoge = Output(UInt((Log2Up(BitWidth : Int) : Int).W))
```

I am not sure if you can use just Log2, try using Log2Up or Log2Down with the syntax as shown above. I guess this should work, let me know if this fixes the error and yeah use UInt instead of Uint

Comment: Some tutorial uses the ```Log2UP``` but chisel3 seems not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Chisel has chisel3.util.log2Ceil(i: Int) which returns the number of bits required to hold `i` values. Your example has a typo `Uint` instead of `UInt` which maybe causing problems. I'm not sure what `BitWidth` in your example is? Is it a `class` or an `Int`, if it's an `Int` it would be better to use the scala convention for lowercase beginnings for variable names. If you have a `val x = UInt(8.W)` and you would like to use the width of `x` in an `IO` declaration it would look like

```
  val a = IO(Input(chiselTypeOf(x)))
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes the ```Uint``` is my typo. The ```chisel3.util.log2Ceil(i: Int)``` works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking strictly to cast, UInts have the [asSInt](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.1.2/index.html#chisel3.core.UInt@asSInt():chisel3.core.SInt) method. See:

Comment: I remember that the ```asSInt``` member in the ```Uint``` can not be used in bit-width declaration, it needs ```Int```, I think.